# Getting for not founding Visual Studio 2017. Reason?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2019, development-environment

```
 C:\Users\himan5hu\Documents\HTML\MyNode\Natours> npm i ndb --global   
C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\ndb -> C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\ndb.js

> node-pty@0.9.0 install C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty
> node scripts/install.js


C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config    
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2017
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt  
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.7.30611.23) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.1274) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer 
to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio 
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.  
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:      
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)  
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)     
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\himan5hu\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\himan5hu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
+ ndb@1.1.5
updated 1 package in 47.034s
```

I have Installed visual studio 2019 with desktop development with C++.
In cmd, npm config install -g windows-build-tools.
cmd- npm config set msvs_version 2017. I dont understand why I am getting this error. Is it bad or I can work ignoring this.